# Why two if statements don't work in one function?

Tags: javascript, function, nested

Working on a function that checks if a user is logged in or out. If logged in, **Log In** button is removed and **Log Out** button displays. If current state is logged out, then **Log In** is displayed and **Log Out** is removed.

It's running in two different functions `loggedIn();` and `loggedOut();`. Each function is built out with ternary operators.

Is there a way to combine these into one function that checks for all conditions? Like `loggedCheck();` so I don't have two different functions running.

Just looking to be more efficient and not over-code things.

```js
isLoggedIn = false;

function loggedIn() {
  isLoggedIn == true ? login.style.display = 'none' : login.style.display = 'block';
}

function loggedOut() {
  isLoggedIn == true ? logout.style.display = 'block' : logout.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">




<body onload="loggedIn(); loggedOut();">
  <div class="container py-3">
    <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="login">Log In</button>
    <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="logout">Log Out</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not likely because both conditions are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is more simple to do:

**with no needs of**:
 - onload function
 - bad global var = *isLoggedIn*

```js
const LoginBlock = document.getElementById('LoginBlock')
    , bt_LogIn   = document.getElementById('login')
    , bt_LogOut  = document.getElementById('logout')
    
bt_LogIn.onclick=_=> {
  LoginBlock.classList.add('loginOff')
}

bt_LogOut.onclick=_=>  {
  LoginBlock.classList.remove('loginOff')
}
```

```css
#LoginBlock > button#login { display: block; }
#LoginBlock > button#logout { display: none; }

#LoginBlock.loginOff > button#login { display: none; }
#LoginBlock.loginOff > button#logout { display: block; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="container py-3" id="LoginBlock" >
    <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="login">Log In</button>
    <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="logout">Log Out</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

if you need:

```
  if (LoginBlock.classList.contains('loginOff')) { // instead of  your global "isLoggedIn"
     // your code
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them into a single function and use a ternary for each.

Two suggestions:

- Use [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) instead of `<body onload="...">` to remove your JavaScript from the HTML (separation of concerns)
- Use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to fetch the elements, instead of relying on [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables).

```js
isLoggedIn = false;

window.onload = () => {
  document.getElementById("login").style.display = isLoggedIn ? 'none' : 'block';
  document.getElementById("logout").style.display = isLoggedIn ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container py-3">
  <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="login">Log In</button>
  <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="logout">Log Out</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted your approach slightly to only using one button and changing it's `textContent` appropriately:

```js
const [btn] = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
let isLoggedIn = false;

btn.onclick = (e) => {
  isLoggedIn = !isLoggedIn;
  btn.textContent = isLoggedIn ? 'Log Out' : 'Log In';
};
```

```html
<button>Log In</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single function like this

```js
let isLoggedIn = false;

const login = document.getElementById('login')
const logout = document.getElementById('logout')

login.addEventListener('click', handleLogin)
logout.addEventListener('click', handleLogin)

function handleLogin() {
  isLoggedIn = !isLoggedIn;

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    login.style.display = 'block';
    logout.style.display = 'none';
    return
  }
  
  login.style.display = 'none';
  logout.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<body onload="handleLogin();">
  <div class="container py-3">
    <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="login">Log In</button>
    <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="logout">Log Out</button>
  </div>
</body>
```